# What are the epimorphisms and monomorphisms in the category of affine varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I have a naive question on algebraic geometry.

To fix a context we consider $\phi:X\to Y$ a morphism between two affine varieties over an algebraic closed field $k$.

This give under the anti-equivalence of categories a k-algebra morphism $\phi^*$ between coordinate algebras of $Y$ and $X$.

However, $\phi^*$ injective doesn't imply $\phi$ surjective. Think for example to the projection of the hyperbola $XY=1$ to the $X$-axis.

Shouldn't the anti-equivalence of categories force a correspondence between injective and surjective morphisms?
It must be that surjective morphism of affine varieties are not the epimorphisms in the categorical sense, but I don't understand why?

I know that for finite morphisms for instance, we have this correspondence.
So I am wondering what are the epimorphisms and monomorphisms in the category of affine varieties?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Moustik

Comment: Monomorphisms in the category of rings give rise to epimorphisms of affine varieties, namely dominant maps. This is not surprising since it is the same in topology: morphisms of varieties are continuous and such maps are uniquely determined on a dense subset.

Comment: Thank @Moos.I think I just figured one thing: if $\phi ^*$ is injective, it is a monomorphism. Then $\phi$ is of course an epimorphism. But epimorphisms are not necessarily surjective... That's just what I was missing...

Comment: Anyway the question stands. Is there a description of epimorphisms and monomorphisms in the category of affine varieties?

Comment: For monomorphisms of affine schemes/epimorphisms of commutative rings, see [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/109/33088).

Comment: @TakumiMurayama I think that link qualifies as answer and should be posted as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am posting my comment as an answer as requested, with some more concrete references.

We start with monomorphisms:

**Proposition** [[Borceux](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511525858), Ex. 1.7.7.d]**.** *A homomorphism of unital commutative rings is a monomorphism if and only if it is injective.*

Epimorphisms are harder to describe; see [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109/33088), and especially [David Rydh's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/161/33088), which states a characterization of monomorphisms among morphisms of schemes which are locally of finite type.

We state a general characterization of epimorphisms of rings:

**Theorem** [[Roby](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=SAC_1967-1968__2__A3_0), Thm. 1]**.** *Let $f \colon R \to S$ be a homomorphism of unital commutative rings. The following are equivalent:*

1. *$f$ is an epimorphism;*
2. *For every $R$-algebra $T$, there exists at most one $R$-algebra homomorphism $S \to T$;*
3. *For all $s \in S$, the relation $1 \otimes s = s \otimes 1$ holds in $S \otimes_R S$;*
4. *The multiplication map $\mu \colon S \otimes_R S \to S$ is injective (in which case it is an isomorphism of $R$-algebras);*
5. *The canonical injection $i_1 \colon S \to S \otimes_R S$ (resp. $i_2 \colon S \to S \otimes_R S$) defined by $s \mapsto s \otimes 1$ (resp. $s \mapsto 1 \otimes s$) is surjective (in which case it is an isomorphism of $R$-algebras);*
6. *The tensor algebra $T_R(S)$ is commutative;*
7. *$S \otimes_R S/R = 0$.*

I've skipped some of the conditions; see [[Roby](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=SAC_1967-1968__2__A3_0)] for more. Roby's article is from [a seminar directed by Samuel](http://www.numdam.org/issues/SAC_1967-1968__2_), which is probably the most thorough source on epimorphisms of rings. Finally, see [[Lazard](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1969__97__81_0)] for results on flat epimorphisms, and [Stacks, [Tag 04VM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VM)] for a modern reference.

Comment: I edited condition 2 from "there exists an..." to "there exists at most one....", translating from the original "*il existe au plus*."  (Note that Roby's algebra homomorphisms carry units to units). Of course existence is not guaranteed, even for nice surjections, e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$ surjects onto both $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ but there's no $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra homomorphism between the latter two.

Comment: @BadamBaplan thank you!