# Does a closed embedding of affine varieties induce a surjective morphism of coordinate rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry

I am basically asking for a converse of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71623/why-does-surjectivity-of-the-induced-map-show-that-a-morphism-of-affine-varietie). Is  it true that if $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ is a closed injective morphism of affine varieties, then the induced $k$ algebra morphism from regular functions on $W$ to regular functions on $V$ is surjective?

Since $\phi$ is closed, $\phi(V)\subseteq W$ is a variety. Intuitively, for $f$ regular on $V$ one would define $g(\phi(x)) = f(x)$ on $\phi(V)$. But is there anything that guarantees that this can be extended to a regular function on $W$?

I know that the categories of affine varieties and of finitely generated $K$-algebras without nilpotents are equivalent, but I've seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142651/what-are-the-epimorphisms-and-monomorphisms-in-the-category-of-affine-varieties) that an epimorphism in the category of $K$-algebras is not a surjective morphism; I would also prefer a category-free approach if it's possible, as I'm not very comfortable with how equivalence of categories behaves w.r.t epimorphisms and monomorphisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is no. You can consider $C \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ given by $x^2 = y^3$ and the morphism $\phi : \mathbb{A}^1 \to C$ given by $z \mapsto (z^3 , z^2)$. I think that this $\phi$ is a bijection, and it is closed (since closed subsets of curves are simply cofinite subsets), but it is not a closed immersion.

Comment: But you should be careful with terminology. A "closed immersion" between affine varieties is (by definition I guess) a morphism for which the corresponding morphisms of algebras is a surjection. Maybe some people will understand "closed embedding" to mean "closed immersion". You consider a closed morphism, which is injective. So a closed morphism which is injective is not necessarily a closed immersion.

Comment: Indeed I had a terminological confusion. I thought "embedding/immersion" simply meant "injective morphism". So one would normally define an immersion as a morphism for which the morphism of algebra is a surjection (and then the first question I liked to shows it's also closed)?

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon A closed immersion is a morphism for which the corresponding morphism of algebras is a surjection. Such a morphism is then closed (the image of closed subset is closed) and injective, but the converse, as we see here, is not true in general. There are also "open immersions" which are defined differently, and there are "immersions", or "locally closed immersions" (which in this context can be defined as compositions of closed and open immersions).

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon - The notion "injective map" is usually referring to a map of sets, a map of topological spaces etc. You seldom use this notion for schemes, since a map of schemes is two things - a map of topological spaces and a map of sheaves of rings.